# Reading registers from a (MCP2515) chip on a CAN Hat

Tags: raspbian, pi-zero, can-bus

I'm using a CAN Hat which talks SPI to the PI.. everything works, as it automatically loads the (MCP2515) drivers and makes the CAN bus accessible via sockets.

However, is there a way to read-back what's on those MCP2515 registers?  Or is that low-layer access not available at the user/root layer?